# How to completely reinstall pipx

Tags: python, pipx

How do I completely reinstall pipx.

I have been installed pipx but I am unable to use it to install eth-brownie. I have uninstalled and reinstalled and it seems to still not be working.

It seems to still be referencing old files not removed.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reinstall pip I would recommend using:

```
pipx reinstall-all
```

This will reinstall all pipx files.